# too much recursion javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
DomReady.ready(function() {
    (function () {
        var Username = document.getElementById("Username").onpaste = function() {Username()};

        function Username(){
            alert("Boom");
        }

    })();
});
```

I am getting too much recursion error in console.
I don't know how to debug it, so if any one can point me out on how to debug it then it will be helpful.

I am getting too much recursion error in console.
I don't know how to debug it, so if any one can point me out on how to debug it then it will be helpful.

Comment: You could have removed the styles part as it is irrelevant.

Comment: check out this: [function-and-variable-with-the-same-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057649/function-and-variable-with-the-same-name)

Comment: @Ananth I am sorry. I will keep that in mind next time. @ abl Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
DomReady.ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("Username").onpaste = username;

    function username(){
        alert("Boom");
    }
});
```