# How hoisting works when function and variable have same name

Tags: javascript

How is the output for below snippets - function.

```
console.log(typeof foo);

function foo() {
  return "bar";
}
var foo = "bar";
```

```
function foo() {
  return "bar";
}
var foo;

console.log(typeof foo);
```

Shouldn't it be undefined due to var foo?

Answer (score 1):

`var foo` redundantly declares the variable and **doesn't assign anything to it**.

It doesn't explicitly assign `undefined` so it doesn't overwrite the existing function value with `undefined`.

Comment: also have a look at this question that has been answered 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057649/function-and-variable-with-the-same-name